# GTK3 button signal errors

Tags: c, runtime-error, gtk3

I am triyng to make a simple GTK3 window in the C language to show a error message when something happens in the main program, to show to the user what error happened. But, when i try to connect a gtk_main_quit function to the button, the GTK process throws these errors:

`GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:04:36.787: instance with invalid (NULL) class pointer`

`GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:04:36.795: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed`

And then i am stumped to how solve this issue. Maybe I am not initializing correctly the menu?

The way i structered it is by a global struct, that is called and allocated in separated functions, that throws me no errors.

Here is the full code of the function

```
int mensagem_erro()
 {
    GtkBuilder *construtor = NULL;

    printf("Alocando a janela...\n");
    construtor = malloc(sizeof construtor);

    alojar_erro();

    printf("Gerando a mensagem de erro...\n");
    snprintf(modelo_estrutura_erro->string_erro, TAMANHO_STRING_ERRO-1,"Erro! Erro n %i, 
    do tipo: %s", errno, strerror(errno));

    printf("Criando a tela de erro...\n");
    construtor = gtk_builder_new_from_file("tela_erro.glade");

    if(construtor==NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro! Erro n %i, do tipo: %s", errno, strerror(errno));
        return FALSE;
    }

    printf("Alocando os dados da tela de erro...\n");
    modelo_estrutura_erro->label_erro = GTK_LABEL(gtk_builder_get_object(construtor, 
    "label_erro"));

    if(modelo_estrutura_erro->label_erro==NULL){printf("Erro ao alocar a 
    estrutura!\n");return FALSE;}

    criar_widget(modelo_estrutura_erro->janela_erro, construtor,"janela_erro");
    criar_widget(modelo_estrutura_erro->box_erro, construtor,"box_erro");
    criar_widget(modelo_estrutura_erro->botao_erro, construtor,"botao_erro");
    printf("Inicializando os sinais da tela de erro...\n");
    g_signal_connect(GTK_WIDGET(modelo_estrutura_erro->botao_erro), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);

    printf("Alocando a mensagem na tela de erro...\n");
    gtk_label_set_text(modelo_estrutura_erro->label_erro, modelo_estrutura_erro-                
    >string_erro);

    printf("Mostrando a janela de erro...\n");
    gtk_widget_show(modelo_estrutura_erro->janela_erro);

    g_object_unref(construtor);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
construtor = malloc(sizeof construtor);
```

1. You need to reserve space with `sizeof *constructor` not with `sizeof constructor`, otherwise you reserve space for a pointer.
2. You replace the space reserved by `malloc` in this line (memory leak):

```c
construtor = gtk_builder_new_from_file("tela_erro.glade");
```

Remove the `malloc` line (related: when using GTK/GLIB always prefer the safe version `g_malloc`)

Regarding your problem:

```c
g_signal_connect(GTK_WIDGET(modelo_estrutura_erro->botao_erro), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
```

Connect the `"clicked"` event with a valid instance, `clicked` wants an object (not a generic widget) as parent.

Replace `GTK_WIDGET(modelo_estrutura_erro->botao_erro)` with `G_OBJECT(modelo_estrutura_erro->botao_erro)`.

Comment: Much thanks for the help! I found the problem that was causing troubles too. I was not allocating correctly the objects in the pointers in the `criar_widget` function, i now have corrected it. Now the windows works flawslessly, i will post the final code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answer above, i was able to correct the code, and now works flawlessly, even with multiple instances of the window.

```
int mensagem_erro()
{
    GtkBuilder *construtor = NULL;

    printf("Criando a tela de erro...\n");
    construtor = gtk_builder_new_from_file("tela_erro.glade");

    if(construtor==NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro! Erro n %i, do tipo: %s", errno, strerror(errno));
        return FALSE;
    }

    printf("Alocando a janela...\n");
    modelo_estrutura_erro = g_malloc(sizeof(*modelo_estrutura_erro));
    modelo_estrutura_erro->string_erro = (char*) g_malloc(sizeof(char[TAMANHO_STRING_ERRO]));

    printf("Gerando a mensagem de erro...\n");
    snprintf(modelo_estrutura_erro->string_erro, TAMANHO_STRING_ERRO-1,"Erro! Erro n %i, do tipo: %s", errno, strerror(errno));

    printf("Alocando os dados da tela de erro...\n");
    modelo_estrutura_erro->label_erro = GTK_LABEL(gtk_builder_get_object(construtor, "label_erro"));

    if(modelo_estrutura_erro->label_erro==NULL){printf("Erro ao alocar a estrutura!\n");return FALSE;}

    modelo_estrutura_erro->janela_erro = criar_widget(modelo_estrutura_erro->janela_erro, construtor,"janela_erro");
    modelo_estrutura_erro->box_erro = criar_widget(modelo_estrutura_erro->box_erro, construtor,"box_erro");
    modelo_estrutura_erro->botao_erro = criar_widget(modelo_estrutura_erro->botao_erro, construtor,"botao_erro");
    printf("Inicializando os sinais da tela de erro...\n");

    //O tipo de sinal clicked necessita de um objeto como parente para funcionar
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(modelo_estrutura_erro->botao_erro), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);

    printf("Alocando a mensagem na tela de erro...\n");
    gtk_label_set_text(modelo_estrutura_erro->label_erro, modelo_estrutura_erro->string_erro);

    printf("Mostrando a janela de erro...\n");
    gtk_widget_show(modelo_estrutura_erro->janela_erro);

    g_object_unref(construtor);
    return TRUE;
}
```